# Flask Jsonify returning a list of objects on one computer and a list containing tuples on another

Tags: python, flask

Both computers are running Flask version 0.12.2, on the same browser version (chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)).

This is an example of the data passed into the jsonify function serialized data:

```
[('Code1', ['website1.com']), ('Code2', ['website2.com'])]
```

The output of the machine without simplejson installed is:

```
[["Code1",["website1.com"]],["Code2",["website2.com"]]]
```

versus this with simplejson installed:

```
[{"code":"Code1",place:["website1.com"]},{"code":"Code2",place:["website2.com"]}]
```

```
from flask import jsonify, Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://localhost:5432/test_db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class myModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'testtable'

    code1 = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
    code2 = db.Column(db.Text)
    def __init__(self, co1, co2):
        self.code1 = co1
        self.code2 = co2

@app.route("/")
def b():
    a = [('Code1', ['website1.com']), ('Code2', ['website2.com'])]
    myModel = test_model.myModel("website1.com", "website2.com")
    myModel = test_model.myModel("website3.com", "website4.com")
    db.session.add(myModel)
    db.session.commit()
    query = test_model.myModel.query.with_entities(test_model.myModel.code1).all()
    print("my model", query, type(query))
    foo = jsonify(query)
    print(foo)
    return foo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When running `python test_file.py` without simplejson installed the output is

```
[
  [
    "website3.com"
  ], 
  [
    "website3.com"
  ], 
  [
    "website3.com"
  ], 
  [
    "website3.com"
  ], 
  [
    "website3.com"
  ], 
  [
    "website3.com"
  ]
]
```

When running with simplejson installed the output is

```
[
  {
    "code1": "website3.com"
  }, 
  {
    "code1": "website3.com"
  }, 
  {
    "code1": "website3.com"
  }, 
  {
    "code1": "website3.com"
  }, 
  {
    "code1": "website3.com"
  }, 
  {
    "code1": "website3.com"
  }, 
  {
    "code1": "website3.com"
  }
]
```

All in all it is something about the interaction between simplejson and flask-sqlalchemy maybe? just happened across it using flask

Answer (score 1):

The issue was having the simplejson python package installed on the machine running ubuntu. It overrides the python json library causing it to return an array of objects instead of an array of arrays as expected when calling jsonify.